# Show Matrix relationship

Tags: matrices

Say $A$ and $B$ are 2x2 matrices with integer entries in the group of matrices with determinant 1, under matrix multiplication. Let $A$ and $B$ have the same first column, show there is exists an integer n where $T=(1,1;0,1)$ such that $A=BT^n$:

Case where the second columns are equal is trivial with n=0.
When the second columns aren't equal, using the $B^{-1}A$ solves that case.

How does this change for entries in the reals and complex?

Comment: Something that might help.. can you explicitly compute the powers $T^n$?

Comment: I take it we're discussing $2 \times 2$ matrices here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I know that it is (1,n;0,1) I can see the effect of adding the first column to the second, I'm trying to use the division algorithm but to no use...

Comment: @JohnHughes yes

Comment: Are you working over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams over the integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A = B T^n$, you must have $T^n = B^{-1} A$.  Now if $A$ and $B$ have their first column the same, let's say
$$ A = \pmatrix{a & c\cr b & d\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{a & e\cr b & f\cr} $$
where $ad-bc = af-be = 1$.  Then 
$$B^{-1} A = \pmatrix{f & -e\cr -b & a\cr} \pmatrix{a & c\cr b & d\cr} = \pmatrix{1 & cf - de\cr 0 & 1\cr} = T^n$$
where $n = cf - de$.

Comment: That was so much more clever than what I was going to do! $+1$

Comment: i realised I was computing AB^-1 instead of the required form you have shown, so i requested to take down the question before you answered, plus the question posed originally had crucial parts missing.

Comment: @WhizKid It's okay! Please leave it up. Every question asked only adds to the lexicon of our site and helps future users who may have similar problems or people who just want to learn math. It is also a great question because the answer is deceptively simple, which is probably not that obvious to most on first blush.

Answer (score 1):

This seems false.

What about 
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \pi \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} ?
$$
Unless you have a really nice definition for irrational powers of a real matrix, I don't see how you're going to find $n$.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add entires must be integers, your example show it isn't the case when the entries are in the reals

Comment: Actually you can compute arbitrary (complex) powers of a nonsingular matrix using the functional calculus.  When (as here) a $2 \times 2$ matrix $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$, $f(T) = f(\lambda) I + f'(\lambda) (T - \lambda I)$.  In this case $\lambda = 1$ and $f(x) = x^p$ has $f(1) = 1$, $f'(1) = p$, so $T^p = I + p(T - I) = \pmatrix{1 & p\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.

Comment: That's really clever...but when $p = 1/2$, it seems to account for only one of the four square roots of $I$ (namely $I$). What do you do if the answer you need for some problem involves one of the others? Regardless, thanks for introducing me to this notion!